# Как объединить 2 меню на мобильных устройствах

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть 2 меню. Нужно, чтобы при разрешении экрана <767px первое меню скрывалось, а выводилось 2-е, но к нему добавлялись все элементы первого, и к ним добавлялся класс `additional-menu-item`. Код, который использую ниже, работает только если при изменении ширины экрана каждый раз обновлять страницу. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно сделать на чистом JavaScript (без jQuery).

HTML:

```
<header class="header">
    <nav class="top-menu">
        <li class="top-menu__item"><a href="#">Top 1</a></li>
        <li class="top-menu__item"><a href="#">Top 2</a></li>
        <li class="top-menu__item"><a href="#">Top 3</a></li>
    </nav>
    <nav class="main-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Main 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Main 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Main 3</a></li>
    </nav>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) { 
   .top-menu {
        display: none;
   }
   .main-menu {
        outline: 1px solid red;
    }
}
```

JS:

```
let mainMenuItems = document.querySelector(".main-menu");

const mediaQuery = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 767px)');

if (mediaQuery.matches) {
        
    let topMenuItemsNew = document.querySelectorAll(".top-menu li");

    for (let liElement of topMenuItemsNew) {
        liElement.className += " additional-menu-item";
    }

    let topMenuItems = document.querySelector(".top-menu");
        
    mainMenuItems.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', topMenuItems.innerHTML);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Не надо измерять экран, браузер умеет распознавать `mobil\desktop.`

Это в `typescript+react`, на чистом `js` почти всё то же самое.

```
let os: string;
if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    os = "mobile";
} else {
    os = "not mobile";
}
```

Потом в зависимости от os что-то типа

```
contents = (os === "mobile") ? this.mobileLayout() : this.desktopLayout();
```

Имитировать mobile можно нажав f12 + иконка наверху слева.

Comment: Garp, благодарю. Но в любом случае код срабатывает только после обновления страницы. А хотелось бы, чтобы срабатывал при изменении ширины экрана в той же Консоли браузера или при изменении ориентации экрана на планшете.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437786/get-the-size-of-the-screen-current-web-page-and-browser-window